# Laravel Spatie\Browsershot Error For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `/home/______/public_html/myfiles/storage/public/cv/file.pdf

Tags: laravel, browsershot

Spatie\Browsershot
Laravel

**My Code :**

```
$save_to_file = storage_path('public/cv/file.pdf');

Browsershot::html('<h1>test<h1>')
->noSandbox()
->save($save_to_file);
```

**The Error :**

```
For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `/home/______/public_html/myfiles/storage/public/cv/file.pdf`.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this : [how to fix Spatie/Browsershot error somehow Chrome did not write a file at `screenshot.pdf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121581/how-to-fix-spatie-browsershot-error-somehow-chrome-did-not-write-a-file-at-scre)

This work for me with spatie/browsershot in GitHub Actions CI.
Although composer install puppetter, installing manually puppetter and chromium on the system made the generation of PDFs work.

> npm install -g puppeteer

> npm install -g chromium