# how to fix Spatie/Browsershot error somehow Chrome did not write a file at `screenshot.pdf`

Tags: php, browsershot

I am trying to create a pdf file using browsershot but getting error.
I installed Browsershot on my cpanel hosting

Here is my code

```
<?php
    require('/home/user name/vendor/autoload.php');
    use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
    
    
    
    
    $url= "https://google.com";
    $html= Browsershot::url($url)->setNodeBinary('/home/username/nodevenv/test/12/bin/node')->setNpmBinary('/home/username/nodevenv/test/12/bin/npm')->save('google.pdf');
    echo 'done';
?>
```

And i am end up with this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Spatie\Browsershot\Exceptions\CouldNotTakeBrowsershot: For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `google.pdf`. Command payload: [] in /home/username/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Exceptions/CouldNotTakeBrowsershot.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/username/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Browsershot.php(601): Spatie\Browsershot\Exceptions\CouldNotTakeBrowsershot::chromeOutputEmpty('google.pdf') #1 /home/username/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Browsershot.php(528): Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot->savePdf('google.pdf') #2 /home/username/public_html/a.php(9): Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot->save('google.pdf') #3 {main} thrown in /home/username/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Exceptions/CouldNotTakeBrowsershot.php on line 13

I don't know what's wrong. How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with

**npm install -g puppeteer

npm install -g chromium**

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Comment: I am getting same issue after doing this.